# cannot insert multiple records in accounting distributions (accountingdistribution)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

when I'm trying to post the Free text invoice in AX 2012 I'm getting following error: "cannot insert multiple records in accounting distributions (accountingdistribution".

I cannot go to the error line even if 'execute business operations in CIL' is unticked

Can you guide me to correct way how to solve this kind of (cannot insert multiple records) errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to debug :(
Maybe you can narrow down the problem with the [Trace Parser] (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149695.aspx)

Comment: "I cannot go to the error line even if 'execute business operations in CIL' is unticked" - just set a breakpoint in \Classes\Info\add